# You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I ran following commands to create a user in minikube, but I'm getting following error:

`You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

Commands I ran:

```
$ mkdir cert && cd cert

$ openssl genrsa -out user1.key 2048

$ openssl req -new -key user1.key -out user1.csr -subj "/CN=user1/O=group1"

$ openssl x509 -req -in user1.csr -CA ~/.minikube/ca.crt -CAkey ~/.minikube/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out user1.crt -days 500

$ kubectl config set-credentials user1 --client-certificate=user1.crt --client-key=user1.key

$ kubectl config set-context user1-context --cluster=minikube --user=user1

$ kubectl config use-context user1-context

$ kubectl get pods
```

So, the last command to get pods is failing. May I know what I am missing?